# Why doesn't program print value?

Tags: python, function, if-statement

I am wondering why the following program does not print 'b'. It is is very simple code; I think it must work; and do not know the reason why it doesn't.

```
def a():
    if b > 10:
        print 'b'
        sys.exit(1)

# main
while 1:
    a()
    b += 1
```

b is global variable. Actual code is more complicated but the structure is the same as mine. I guess when I call a() function and if b is greater than 10, it shows 'b'. However, it does not go inside if-statement.

Would you help me out how to solve?

Thanks.

Comment: Does it not print anything at all?

Comment: Wait, how does it print 'b' if it does not enter the body of the `if`? Please clarify.

Comment: I have tried your code with `globla b` in front of `def a():` and it works fine with 'b' printed. It did go inside if-statement. (Python 2.7.2 Win32)

Comment: @Mayli Absolutely not! It raises `NameError: global name 'b' is not defined`. The solution is not the `global b`. It's `b = 0` before the loop starts!

Comment: @Bird Jaguar IV: It does not print anything at all.

Comment: @delnan: it cannot go inside. I've checked out several times, but it haven't.

Comment: @Maria Zverina:Yeah, I've done with the approach even though I did not write down here. It does not work. I've lost.

Comment: @SangwonChae Can you put here the **exact** code you are running? This raises an exception!

Comment: @jadkik94 I mean `global b;b=0`, the author didn't mention the initial value of b. This question is so boring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Global vars are not the usual way to go. You may prefer the usage of [nested functions](http://marakana.com/bookshelf/python_fundamentals_tutorial/functional_programming.html) instead:

```
import sys

def outer(value=0):
    count = [value]
    print "started at:", count[0]
    def inner(x=1):
        print "current val:", count[0]
        count[0] += x
        if count[0] > 10:
            print "stopped at:", count[0]
            sys.exit(0)
    return inner

f = outer(5)
while True:
    f(1)
```

Answer (score 3):

Globals are horrid learn not to use them, try something like this

```
import sys
def a(value):
    if value > 10:
        print value
        print "Greater than 10!"
        sys.exit(0)
b = 0
while True:
    a(b)
    b += 1
```

Comment: I've tried to the same approach as you answered, but it does not work.

Comment: You need to delete the `.pyc` and restart the interpreter

Comment: While you are completely correct that globals should not be used, this doesn't actually answer the question.

Comment: @StevenBurnap The question is unclear and can't be reproduced

Comment: Other functions work very well, but this function cannot work correctly. I do not know why it is not working.

Answer (score 1):

Another answers suggests not using globals, and I agree. If you still want to use globals, you should define `b` outside of the loop first.(if you do, then please post the complete code, because apart from that, it should work (and it does)).

Now, `global b` in the function definition is not necessary, because python guesses it is a global variable when you try to access it before assigning. But since it is not defined it raises an `NameError`:

```
NameError: global name 'b' is not defined
```

If you don't see that, so there's something else, you're not showing the actual code that has a problem.

This gives you in the end, something similar:

```
import sys
def a():
    global b
    if b > 10:
        print 'b'
        sys.exit(1)

b = 0
# main
while 1:
    a()
    b += 1
```

Comment: This works correctly. Is copy pasting it not working? I don't think so...  Do you get any exception/output/anything... What is your actual code doing? We really need more details to help you, because that is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

just my 2 cents: forget global variables.

anyway, this should work

```
def a():
    global b
    if b > 10:
        print 'b'
        sys.exit(1)
```

**EDIT** FUUUUUUUUUUUUUUU

Although I fully agree with Jackob on how you should use functions arguments and avoid globals, just for the record, here's the solution with global:

```
def a():
    global b
    if b > 10:
        print 'b'
        sys.exit(1)

# main
b = 0
while 1:
    a()
    b += 1
```

Comment: Here too: -1 That `global` is redundant as `b` is not assigned to. And otherwise that code is identical to OP's.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define b before "+="ing it.

```
def a():
    if b > 10:
        print 'b'
        sys.exit(1)

# main
b = 0 # HERE
while 1:
    a()
    b += 1
```

By the way, as many had told you: avoid globals.